# Location filter not working in WP Google Maps Pro

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

I have set up a location finder on my map, however the search filter does not appear to be working. For example, when I type in the name of a town or city i.e London in the search bar and filter it to display locations within a 20 mile radius, it should display these below the map.

Instead it still continues to display all location set up on my map.

Just to follow on from this, if I check the box next to 'Display Categories/Locations Tab' the filter does then work, but the down side to this is it of course displays a 'locations' tab on the map, which I do not want.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the link where you are experiencing the issue?